# Partitioning a single vacuum chamber to isolate out-gassing components?

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum

Planning a DIY vacuume chamber that would contain motors and electronics for manipulating in random experiments

My thought is to section the chamber into two parts: clean and dirty - the dirty part containing the motors and such that would be expected to out-gas until the cows came home, the clean chamber being the actual working volume. Any mechanisms that needed to breach the partition could be simply sealed with a flexible plastic membrane since the pressure differential between the walls would be very low.

Between the two volumes would be a stray atom trap consisting of a tapered tube with the wider opening in the clean chamber, the idea being once a high-vacuum was achieved the last of the atoms in the clean partition would eventually encounter the wide end of the trap and assuming they were within the traps acceptance angle be deflected within the tube to the dirty side, there along with the products of out-gassing they would be more likely to encounter the vacuum port than the small diameter opening of the trap.

Does this arrangement sound feasible? Is it already tried and tested (if so what should I be searching under)? Are there more reliable atom trap / valve mechanisms that could be used to separate the partitions (keeping in mind the DIY nature)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the atom trap though. But I do have a cheaper alternative for your flexible plastic membrane:

1. You can transfer Rotation Force into your "clean" chamber with the use of Magnet. This can be done by attaching a Magnet outside the chamber and another Inside the Chamber. Rotating the Outer Magnet will rotate the Inner Magnet. Depends on how you want to use it anyway.

Comment: Or a ferrofluidic feedthru (depending on how high the high-vacuum is).

Comment: Am thinking more along the lines of a telerobotic arm with multiple degrees of movement.